# A very basic applet / swing requirement

Tags: java, swing, applet

As I'm not much into client side programming, I request for help.

Use case: A html file has as an applet/swing component which has a single line edit box which takes url to a file and a submit button. If button is clicked, program must read file specified as input and display as html file in a new browser window.

Requirement: Using Java 1.5, how to display that input file in html format (.html) in a new browser window?

Please help. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/533622/GUI/java/very-basic-applet-swing-requirement

Comment: thanks much camickr for the note. i made a cross post note on code ranch and visited here to do same but, noticed it's already done by you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just upload that file to a server and after a submit - redirect to that file.

Comment: I think its something like this `getAppletContext().showDocument("hello.html");` Could be wrong, been awhile since Ive used Applets

Comment: You are right! And, just need to pass "_blank" as 2nd argument to showDocument. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Swing components can actually render simple HTML:

[How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

I am not going to give you all of the code to read in the files and pass it to swing components.  But it should not be hard to read the file, create a JFrame and add a JPanel with the HTML you want to render to it.  The examples above get you most of the way there other than reading the file.

Comment: I dont disagree with your answer, but I would say that Swing's built in rendering of HTML is terrible (minimal). It would probably depend on what type of HTML needs to be rendered. Perhaps invoking the default OS's browser pointed to the newly uploaded file would be a better solution since he says "New Window"

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right.  When I first read the post, I thought he was asking to specifically render the HTML in swing.  On second reading it seems like they may just want to open it, in which case a browser word be much better :D